# Is there some similar feature in Java as 'attributes' in Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi

Is there some similar feature in Java as 'attributes' in Delphi ?

Example explanation of Attributes in Delphi:
http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=476

Att.

Comment: That link doesn't make it super-clear to me what they are; are they basically [annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html)?

Comment: Yes Dave, it's what I was looking for. Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that article, you're looking for [Java Annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html). They let you do things like:

```
@SomeInfo(author = "Bob", year = 1993)
class Foo {
    @SomeInfo(author = "me", somethingElse = "abcdefg")
    private int x = 5;

    @SomeInfo(author = "Fred", column = "order")
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

where `@SomeInfo` is an annotation. They can be applied to classes, fields, and methods, and they carry metadata about the thing they annotate, which can be read at runtime if they have the appropriate retention. E.g:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SomeInfo {
    String author();
    int year() default -1;
    String column() default "";
    String somethingElse() default "";
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<AnnotatedElement> annotatedElements =
            new ArrayList<AnnotatedElement>();
        annotatedElements.add(Foo.class);
        annotatedElements.add(Foo.class.getDeclaredField("x"));
        annotatedElements.add(Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("getX"));
        for (AnnotatedElement annotatedElement : annotatedElements) {
            System.out.println("Author of {" + annotatedElement + "} = " +
                annotatedElement.getAnnotation(SomeInfo.class).author());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The nice thing in Java is that these annotations can be restricted to specific Targets (for example `@Target({ElementType.FIELD)})` - in Delphi, no such restriction is possible, which means the compiler will not complain. And Retention policies are missing too in Delphi, would be nice to have RetentionPolicy.SOURCE and RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME in Delphi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an attributes is a way to store diffrent variable together.

That is what OOP is (Very)generally about (And so is JAVA), creating classes that represents entities. Those entities are basically made of different variables (or attributes)

This example from your link and a comparison to JAVA will make it clearer:

```
MyAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
 FName: string;
 FAge: Integer;
public
 constructor Create(const Name : string; Age : Integer);
 property Name : string read FName write FName;
 property Age : Integer read FAge write FAge;
end;
```

Is just like a little class in JAVA:

```
public class Customer()
{
  String Fname;
  int FAge;

  public Customer()
  {
   /*constructor code*/
  }
}
```

and creating the class from your example:

```
  TMyClass = class
 public
  [MyAttribute('Malcolm', 39)]
```

Is just like creating a new person object:

```
Customer[] cust1= new Customer['Malcolm', 39]
```

Comment: That's only half of what they are: the Delphi attributes can be applied to methods as shown in the example--hence my question about annotations. They're not just a class.

Comment: They're not classes at all. But he asked for a similar feature, and as I see it, class is similar to an attribute if we look at what it gives you, that is an access to different variables, from different places and a way to store them together to create an entity.

Comment: Delphi attributes are applied to properties and provide meta data. A class isn't a good comparison because delphi already *had* classes-it's what the attribute was applied to in the example.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. And +1 Ryan for the good explanation :)